# Is there any way to send a link with discord.py with no embeds at all?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been researching this question and I haven't found an answer anywhere, would anyone know how to not avoid embeds when you send a link with discord.py?

Comment: This question has been asked too many times already, you can google it and find an answer in less than a minute… Please do a better job when researching, this is not enough.

Comment: Searching "Link without embed discord" on google, the first two results are: https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/4be938/tip_want_link_without_preview_use_backslash_after/ and https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206342858--How-do-I-disable-auto-embed-#:~:text=Pro%20Tip%3A%20If%20you%20want,in%20''%20tags.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should be able to do that by enclosing the link in `< >`.